# Why Wifi connection get lost when bluetooth scanning?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an application that scan bluetooth devices continuously and when it detect a device(my devices make advertisement every three minutes once ) send its scanRecord data to a webservice(Works like bluetooth gateway). It works fine first time but after nearly 30 sec. wifi connection get lost. How can I fix this issue. My onResume code:

```
@Override
   public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();

   if(!mScanner.isScanning())
    {
      startScan();
    }

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

Start scan:

```
private void startScan() {
        final boolean mIsBluetoothOn = mBluetoothUtils.isBluetoothOn();
        final boolean mIsBluetoothLePresent = mBluetoothUtils.isBluetoothLeSupported();
        mDeviceStore.clear();
        updateItemCount(0);

        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter(this, mDeviceStore.getDeviceCursor());
        mList.setAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);

        mBluetoothUtils.askUserToEnableBluetoothIfNeeded();
        if (mIsBluetoothOn && mIsBluetoothLePresent) {
            mScanner.scanLeDevice(-1, true);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
```